# How to use :before to add fixed with div with flex box underneath vertically centered

Tags: html, css

I am try to make the top box (created with :before) have a maximum width of 100px, but also make sure it is above the 'bottom'.

This can be achieved by making .aligner's flex-direction as column, but then everything is vertically aligned inside, while I need the top to always be in the top left corner.

```css
.Aligner {
 height:90px;
 display: flex;
 align-items: start;
 flex-wrap:wrap;
 border:thin solid blue;
}

.Aligner:before {
 width:100%;
 content:'top width of 100px';
 border:thin solid black;
 display:table;
}
```

```html
<div class="Aligner">
 Bottom
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Without your html i cant give an accurate answer but i think what you need is the flex property of `order:` giving an order to the item being displayed as flex will adjust the order in which the items are placed but make sure all children of the div / elements being displayed as flex are given an order or those without might be aligned ahead of those with order property.

Comment: As we know that :before always make its content within its container and that is coming right too. If you want to make it outside the border then take the text bottom in another container and apply your border on that.

Comment: @Robbie sorry for the not woking fiddle i think you already have what your looking for as shown in this [js fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/bobbyaxe61/3q0sgvzu/) check to see if they are other css properties interfering with your current div